# HANA select CURRENT_DATE output empty cell

Tags: sql, hana-sql-script

I have a very simple problem with HANA SQL but I really can't understand the solution. My target is to output the current date.

If I write the following query in HANA Studio, it output an empty cell

```
SELECT current_date "current date" FROM DUMMY;
```

[image]

while if I write the following, it gives the current_date as output.

```
SELECT DISTINCT calendar_date "current date"
from CALTABLE
where calendar_date=current_date;
```

Why the first and the second query give different results?

Comment: Can you add details on how you executed the query (i.e. which client, etc)? I copied your query on `dummy` and executed it. On my system it returns the expected result.

Comment: In addition, can you please check the result of `SELECT 'hello world' FROM dummy`. From your screenshot it seems like there is no record returned from `dummy`, which is different from an empty cell (= one record, but no data).